# OpenCv Unspecified error (The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?))

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm using openCV 2.4.10 and  trying to implement something like what is here:

https://github.com/andrewssobral/vehicle_detection_haarcascades

and I have generated files like above project's cars.xml, but when I try to load one of them, I get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?)) in cvRead, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp, line 4991
```

and here's my loading code:

```
CvHaarClassifierCascade *cascade;
cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad("cascade-1.xml", 0, 0, 0);
```

As I said it loads one of my xml files without problem, but it gives that error on another file. I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: can you post a working and non-working xml file (if not too big)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre working: https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZteI2ZJz4vN0T4PF401ehWRjx9R4IaiaUV    and not working: https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZieI2ZBHat0C8AcyuSwuKqsTyKKuzyQTu7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenCV 2.4](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html) documentation suggests usage of [`CascadeClassifier`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html?highlight=cascadeclassifier#cascadeclassifier) class. It successfully loads your `cascade1.xml` file. Here is how you can use `CascadeClassifier` in C++:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
  CascadeClassifier cascade;
  if( !cascade.load( "d:\\OpenCV\\cascade1.xml" ) )
  { 
    std::cout << "Error during loading";
    return -1; 
  }

  Mat pic = imread("d:\\Samples\\Cars\\test.jpg");

  Mat picGray;
  cvtColor( pic, picGray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

  std::vector<Rect> objs;
  cascade.detectMultiScale( picGray, objs, 1.1, 2, 0, Size(0, 0) );

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use different variables of type **CvHaarClassifierCascade** type for loading different xml files and also perform detection differently with them.

As far as your xml files are concerned both are working fine and you can check that by python code below.

```
import cv2
a=cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade1.xml')
b=cv2.CascadeClassifier('cars.xml')
img=cv2.imread('car.jpg')
gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cars_carcode=a.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
cars_car=b.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)

def car(cars):
    cars=a.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in cars:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray=gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        roi_color=img[y:y+h,x:x+w]

    return (gray,img)

cv2.imshow('Cars Detected by carcode1.xml',car(cars_carcode)[1] )
cv2.imshow('Cars Detected by cars.xml',car(cars_car)[1] )   
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Okay it works, however I need it in cpp, not python, and I'm not using both at the same time, I just load one each time to use.

Comment: Also the code you provided has problem, to be specific in `car` function

Comment: @Abhishek . I am not able to load my xml file even. What to do for that ? xml is trained by myself.